# Busqueda no encontrada en angular ¿cómo realizarlo?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular10

Deseo hacer un input de busqueda, que al no encontrar resultados, aparezca un alert que diga que no se han encontrado resultados, y que desaparezca cuando quite la busqueda del input ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

```
  searchCharacter( query: string ) {
  this.loading = true;
  this.rYMSrv.searchCharacter( query ).subscribe( (data: any) => {
    this.charactersList = data.results;
    this.loading = false;
  }, error => {
    this.notFound = error.ok;
  });
```

}

```
<div class="container mt-3">
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" *ngIf="notFound == false">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Error 404</h4>
  <p>There's nothing called {{ query.value }}</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="mb-0">Probably here's the thing you were searching</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchCharacter( query: string ) {
  this.loading = true;

  this.rYMSrv.searchCharacter( query ).subscribe( (data: any) => {
    this.charactersList = data.results;
    this.loading = false;
  }, error => {

    // en caso de error establecer notFound en true
    this.notFound = true;

  });
```

La condición del `ngIf` debe ser:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" *ngIf="notFound">
```

Si es un input normal se puede reaccionar a algún evento como `keyup`

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="notFound = false" />
```

Así al modificar el contenido del input el alert desaparece.

**Actualización:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" *ngIf="notFound">
  A simple primary alert—check it out!
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  notFound = true;

  constructor(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.notFound = false;
    },2000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Funciona, sin embargo el alert se queda aunque quite lo que busqué en el input, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Agregué ejemplo para quitar el alert usando un input normal al modificar su contenido. Si no es lo que necesitas puedes agregar más detalles de como se quita el contenido del input.

Comment: No ha funcionado, intenté con un [ngClass] y tampoco logré hacer que el alert desapareciera cuando no se encuentra nada en la busqueda.

Comment: Me parece que el problema está en que  no se  cambia el valor de  la variable `notFound` en el lugar adecuado. Agregué un ejemplo con un timeout. Siempre que se cambie el valor de `notFound` el alert debe ocultarse/mostrarse.

Comment: Cuando no se encuentran resultados la API devuelve código 404 o siempre un 200?

Comment: Código 404 not found

Comment: Agrega el html del componente.